# Laravel 5.4 : SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5.4

I know there is a lot of topics on this error but it seems that I already try almost everything and it doesn't work at all.

So I've set up my .env file like this:

```
APP_NAME=Neuralia
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=(key)
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_LOG_LEVEL=debug
APP_URL=http://127.0.0.1:8000

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=neuralia
DB_USERNAME=username
DB_PASSWORD=password
```

and my config/database.php like this:

```
 'mysql' => [
        'driver' => 'mysql',
        'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
        'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'neuralia'),
        'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'username'),
        'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', 'password'),
        'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
        'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
        'prefix' => '',
        'strict' => true,
        'engine' => null,
    ],
```

I tried with host => localhost, I cleared my config / cache and dump-autoload but I still get the error when I try to create a user from the register form.

I can use php artisan migrate:refresh etc but not the register / login stuff :/

do you have any ideas please?
Thanks

Comment: If you're running `php artisan serve` stop it and re run it.

Comment: try 'engine' =>'InnoDB';

Comment: Thanks guys for the reply but unfortunately it doesn't work :/